# can mootools change the attribute of a css .class so that the change is reflected across all elements that belong to that class?

Tags: css, mootools

similar to to this here...

http://www.shawnolson.net/a/503/altering-css-class-attributes-with-javascript.html

i know i can change each element's style's individually, but i want to change a lot of elements styles at the same time, and the browser seems to struggle over about 40 elements.

thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can, quite easily.

```
$$('.someClass').addClass('newClass');
```

This will add **newClass** to every **someClass** element - in your case the 40 elements you have.

This is the literal answer to your question.

That said, I believe what you're really trying to do is generate a specific CSS class on the fly.

And that's something far more complicated. I suggest using this MooTools plugin: http://mootools.net/forge/p/moocss

Comment: awesome - addClass & removeClass ought to do the job!

thanks again Oskar!

Comment: Is it not possible to modify a css' class' properties with mootools, instead of adding and removing classes from each element as in the example above, or instead of adding & removing classes from the document head as with moocss?